# Setting a Date Parameter in an insert query in vba?

Tags: sql, vba, date, ms-access

When attempting to insert a vba `Date` obtained from the `Now` function, I get the error:

> "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Since I counted the parameters already I'm going to have to assume this has to do with trying to assign the date to the parameter `v_logdate` below:

```
Dim timeOfExecution As Date
timeOfExecution = Now
' ...

' INSERT a log record that says that this guy was 
Dim qdef1 As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdef1 = db.QueryDefs("InsertAllTimeSyncLogRecord")

With qdef
     ' ...set some other parameters
    .Parameters("v_logdate").Value = timeOfExecution ' timeOfExecution
     ' ...set some other parameters
End With

qdef1.Execute , dbFailOnError
```

My insert statement (`InsertAllTimeSyncLogRecord`) looks like this:
In the `AllTimeSyncLog` table the `LogDate` field the parameter will be inserted into is a `Date/Time` type.

```
INSERT INTO AllTimeSyncLog ( 
   abradcwhash, hash, LogDate, firstname, lastname, 
   cohortid, email, department, [password], method, username 
)
VALUES (
    v_abradcwhash, v_hash, v_logdate, v_firstname, v_lastname, 
    v_cohortid, v_email, v_department, v_password, v_method, v_username
);
```

Is there some other way that I need to be assigning the `timeOfExecution` `Date` to the `v_logdate` parameter in my `InsertAllTimeSyncLogRecord` DAO.QueryDef?

Comment: You assign your saved query def to `qdef1`, but then you use `qdef` (without the trailing `1`) in your `with` clause.  Is this a typo translating to SO or the source of your problem?

Comment: when im inserting date from vba into sql server i usually format it like this before insertion `'" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss") & "'`

Comment: Are you using an external data source (e.g. SQL Server) or Access' built-in database engine (JET)? Which version of Access are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth mentioning that in MS Access, you need to surround dates with pound signs  (#) , though I'm not sure if that applies to querydef parameters, I would assume so.